# How to save variable values into list

Tags: lists, etoolbox, variable

I want to save the content of a token into a list like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    \def\abc{1}
    \listgadd{\lista}{\abc}
    \def\abc{2}
    \listgadd{\lista}{\abc}
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{#1}
    \dolistloop{\lista}
\end{document}
```

I want it to output 12, but it's outputting 22.

Comment: `\listxadd{\lista}{\abc}`  would work (but is sensible only if your content can be expanded fully)

Comment: It worked as intended, even in a more complex environment. Thank you

Comment: I suppose you want to do something else with the accumulated data, rather than just printing it. Can you please be more specific? There are much better tools than `etoolbox` lists nowadays.

Comment: It's pretty complicated. I'm not sure if I'm able to explain it fully. I'm creating environments for exercises and answers, but I want to be able to write the answer right after the exercise, but it should appear at the end of the document. So I'm using xsavebox for that, but not every exercise will have an answer at the end (some of them will be displayed after the exercise), so I'm writing the codes of those exercises into the list, and then looping through the list to generate them automatically at the end. And I'm making hyperlinks from the exercise to the answer and back.

Comment: I've just needed a way to save the codes of exercises, and then use them as names of saveboxes, so etoolbox was enough for me, but if you have any better ideas I will gladly learn something new.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as said OP, it is solved by comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just gonna post it as an answer, so we can close it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    \def\abc{1}
    \listxadd{\lista}{\abc}
    \def\abc{2}
    \listxadd{\lista}{\abc}
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{#1}
    \dolistloop{\lista}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comment, an expl3 sequence variable is a list, and can be named.

But for a specific solution, a lot depends on the details of your use-case: packages, tool-chain, compiler, etc.

[image: qanda]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{xparse}

%-------------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn


        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { cno }



\tl_new:N \g_qa_namespace_tl











%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \qa_funcprintq:n #1 { 
    % 1=qa pair
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_tmpa_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { #1 }

   \tl_set:Nx
    \l_tmpa_tl
    {
                \seq_item:Nn
                    \l_tmpa_seq
                    { 1 }  %Q
        }

%   \tl_set:Nx
%       \l_tmpb_tl
%       {
%               \seq_item:Nn
%                   \l_tmpa_seq
%                   { 2 }  %A
%       }

        \int_gincr:N
            \g_tmpa_int

    \noindent
    Q ~ 
    \int_use:N
        \g_tmpa_int
    \space -- ~
    \tl_use:N
    \l_tmpa_tl
   \tex_par:D
}


%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \qa_funcprinta:n #1 { 
    % 1=qa pair
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_tmpa_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { #1 }

%   \tl_set:Nx
%       \l_tmpa_tl
%       {
%               \seq_item:Nn
%                   \l_tmpa_seq
%                   { 1 }  %Q
%       }

   \tl_set:Nx
    \l_tmpb_tl
    {
                \seq_item:Nn
                    \l_tmpa_seq
                    { 2 }  %A
        }

        \int_gincr:N
            \g_tmpa_int

    \noindent
    A ~ 
    \int_use:N
        \g_tmpa_int
    \space -- ~
    \tl_use:N
    \l_tmpb_tl
   .
   \tex_par:D
}




%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \qa_funcprintqa:n #1 { 
    % 1=qa pair
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_tmpa_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { #1 }

   \tl_set:Nx
    \l_tmpa_tl
    {
                \seq_item:Nn
                    \l_tmpa_seq
                    { 1 }  %Q
        }

   \tl_set:Nx
    \l_tmpb_tl
    {
                \seq_item:Nn
                    \l_tmpa_seq
                    { 2 }  %A
        }

        \int_gincr:N
            \g_tmpa_int

    \noindent
    Q ~ 
    \int_use:N
        \g_tmpa_int
    \space -- ~
    \tl_use:N
    \l_tmpa_tl
    \space (
    \tl_use:N
    \l_tmpb_tl
            )
   \tex_par:D
}










%****************************************************
%* main commands
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \qaloadaseq } { o m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_qa_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_qa_namespace_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_qa_rwe \g_qa_namespace_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_qa_rwe \g_qa_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_qa_rwe \g_qa_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_qa_rwe \g_qa_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            { , } 
            { #3 }



}




%****************************************************
%**
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \qaprintq } { o m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_qa_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_qa_namespace_tl { #1 } }


        \int_gset:Nn
            \g_tmpa_int
            { 0 }
            
        \group_begin:               
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_qa_rwe \g_qa_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \qa_funcprintq:n
        \group_end:

}


%****************************************************
%**
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \qaprinta } { o m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_qa_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_qa_namespace_tl { #1 } }


        \int_gset:Nn
            \g_tmpa_int
            { 0 }
            
        \group_begin:               
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_qa_rwe \g_qa_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \qa_funcprinta:n
        \group_end:

}





%****************************************************
%**
%****************************************************
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \qaprintqa } { o m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_qa_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_qa_namespace_tl { #1 } }


        \int_gset:Nn
            \g_tmpa_int
            { 0 }
            
        \group_begin:               
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_qa_rwe \g_qa_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                    \qa_funcprintqa:n
        \group_end:

}


\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\qaloadaseq[qa]{set1}{
What is $1+1$?;2
,What is half of twice two and a half?;Two and a half
,Are {1, 3, 5, 7} odd or even?;Odd
}


\section*{Questions}
\qaprintq[qa]{set1}


\section*{Answers}
\qaprinta[qa]{set1}


\section*{Teacher's Handbook}
\qaprintqa[qa]{set1}


\end{document}
```